# Passing Class type as parameter

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, parameters, telerik

I'm using Telerik controls UI for WPF and they have a `StyleManager.ApplicationTheme`.  Each "theme" is a class `Telerik.Windows.Controls.CrystalTheme` and each theme has a "palette" `Telerik.Windows.Controls.CrystalPalette` (`public NotInheritable Class`) ... example:

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls.CrystalPalette
Telerik.Windows.Controls.GreenPalette
Telerik.Windows.Controls.MaterialPalette
' ... etc. (about 19 of them)

' All valid assignments
CrystalPalette.Palette.FontSizeXS = 8
MaterialPalette.Palette.FontSizeL = 14
```

I'm tring to setup a `Sub` that will set `FontSizes` based on the `ThemePalette` ... example:

```
Public Function DoSomething() As Boolean
' ...
   ApplyThemeFontSizes(CrystalPalette)
' ...
End Function

Private Sub ApplyThemeFontSizes(Of T)()

     Try

         T.Palette.FontSizeXS = 8
         T.Palette.FontSizeS = 10
         T.Palette.FontSize = 12
         T.Palette.FontSizeL = 14
         T.Palette.FontSizeXL = 16

     Catch ex As Exception

         ' TODO: Log error to file (possible the Theme doesn't have a "Palette")

     End Try

End Sub
```

This code doesn't work and I'm trying to jog my memory on how I can make this work without using Reflection. I don't have any control over the Telerik classes.

I've searched for similar, but the results were not what I'm trying to achieve (i.e. I don't have control over the Telerik classes).

Suggestions?

Comment: In c# you can do like this
private void ApplyThemeFontSize<T>(T theme)
where T : Theme
{
   //your code
}

Comment: The VB equivalent to the previous comment would be `...(Of T As Theme)`, though based on the answer below, it doesn't appear that this would work as there isn't a parent type or interface that has the items you're looking for.  Fortunately or unfortunately (depending on your perspective) .NET generics do not behave like C++ templates, there must be a defined type or interface that provides any properties or methods you call on anything typed as a generic parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Reflection which is last resort since Reflection is so slow ... fortunately the call instance is usually one time at startup and when the user changes a theme.

```
ApplyThemeFontSizes(Office2019Palette.Palette)

    Private Sub ApplyThemeFontSizes(ByVal palette As ThemePalette)

    Try

        TrySetPaletteProperty(palette, "FontSizeXS", 10 + Me.FontOffset)
        TrySetPaletteProperty(palette, "FontSizeS", 12 + Me.FontOffset)
        TrySetPaletteProperty(palette, "FontSize", 14 + Me.FontOffset)
        TrySetPaletteProperty(palette, "FontSizeL", 16 + Me.FontOffset)
        TrySetPaletteProperty(palette, "FontSizeXL", 18 + Me.FontOffset)

    Catch ex As Exception

        ' TODO: Log error to file 

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub TrySetPaletteProperty(ByVal palette As ThemePalette, ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal newValue As Object)

    Try

        ' Set FontSize property values
        Dim propertyInfo = palette.[GetType]().GetProperty(propertyName)
        If propertyInfo IsNot Nothing Then
            propertyInfo.SetValue(palette, newValue)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        ' TODO: Log error to file 

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ThemePalette` type is the base type of all concrete palettes like `CrystalPalette`, `Office2016Palette` and so on. This type is abstract and does not provide any properties for colors or font sizes, because they are **specific to any theme**, which means you cannot create a generalized procedure that sets the `FontSizeXS` property on all themes. This property does not even exist in many themes like *Office2016*.

Create a procedure for each theme palette that you use in your application and pass in the concrete instance.

```
Private Sub ApplyThemeFontSizes(ByVal palette As CrystalPalette)
    palette.FontSizeXS = 8
    ' ...set other theme specific properties.
End Sub
```

Palettes are singletons, but you can get their  instance using the `Palette` property.

```
Public Function DoSomething() As Boolean
' ...
   ApplyThemeFontSizes(CrystalPalette.Palette)
' ...
End Function
```